# Looking for a way to display Google Adsense in IPhone application

Tags: iphone, admob, adsense

My client has saved lot of Google Adsense javascripts in his db and displaying in his website.
Now he wants to display those javascripts ads in his IPhone application.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Google Adsense is mainly for websites I think the better way might be to implement a mobile version of your website. I am not sure how it is going to look as most of the adsense JavaScript is configured to be displayed on a website and not on mobile website.